# Delete a value in a collection Mongo. Example attached

Tags: mongodb

I have this document inside a collection in Mongo and I would like to delete the "7552" : "RTEST" in de bakendData and "7552" in data. How could do it using commands?

```
{

  "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
  "contractId" : "55528fxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "field1": [
    {
      "name":"example",
      "backendData": {
        "map": {
          "7552" : "RTEST",
          "3511" : "TESTR",
          "5312" : "JKTLE",
          "5310" : "INVTS"
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "defaultOrder": [
          "7552",
          "3511",
          "5312",
          "5310"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
      "contractId" : "55528fxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "field1": [
        {
          "name":"example",
          "backendData": {
            "map": {
              "3511" : "TESTR",
              "5312" : "JKTLE",
              "5310" : "INVTS"
            }
          },
          "data": {
            "defaultOrder": [
              "3511",
              "5312",
              "5310"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I try something like that but it doesn't work:

```
db.collection.update(
  { contractId: "55528..............." },
  { $pull: {field1: [ { backendData: { map: {7552: "RTEST"} } }] }}
);
```

Also I would like to add new values. Example:

```
"backendData": {
        "map": {
          "3511" : "TESTR",
          "5312" : "JKTLE",
          "5310" : "INVTS",
          "5355" : "IRZTS",
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "defaultOrder": [
          "3511",
          "5312",
          "5310",
          "5355"
        ]
      }
```

Can someone help me?
Thank in advance

[I attached an image with the document in Robot 3T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saaPe.png)

Answer (score 0):

I expect someone will provide a much shorter answer, but here's one way to remove and add the items you want with one `update`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  // match the doc by _id
  "_id": ObjectId("55528f000000000000000000")
},
[
  { // rebuild field1
    "$set": {
      "field1": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$field1",
          "in": {
            // merge what's there plus filtered map plus new object
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              { "backendData": {
                  "map": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                      { "$arrayToObject": {
                          "$filter": {
                            "input": {
                              "$objectToArray": "$$this.backendData.map"
                            },
                            "as": "stuff",
                            "cond": {
                              // keep everything except object with 7552 key
                              "$ne": [ "$$stuff.k", "7552" ]
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      { "5355": "IRZTS" }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              { "data": {
                  "defaultOrder": {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                      { "$filter": {
                          "input": "$$this.data.defaultOrder",
                          "as": "someNum",
                          "cond": {
                            // keep everything except 7552
                            "$ne": [ "$$someNum", "7552" ]
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      [ "5355" ]
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8ctAxRmlnFl).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Really useful, although one question, when I run the code the field "name":"example" appears at the end instead above the "backendData", how can I put this in the correct place?

Comment: @Sara I'm not sure.  I see many SO Q/As about MongoDB object ordering, and there is mention of it in the MongoDB docs too.  On mongoplayground.net, even just doing `db.collection.find()` on the collection seems to reorder the output.  Whether this is just an output presentation "feature", or an indication of "storage order", I don't know.  In my MongoDB collections/docs/queries, I try not have order be significant, but I suppose others might be affected more.

Comment: I'll see it change the order only in mongoplayground.net but not when I execute the command in the terminal so it's perfect. Thank you for your help.